# best way to process large json file in angularjs and store in $rootScope

Tags: json, angularjs

I have an app that prior to loading the 1st page needs to process a json file that contains all the content of the app.

Where is the best place to do this process? is it a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in a service and store it in `LocalStorage` like this:

```
//save it
localStorage.setItem('myLargeObject', JSON.stringify(myLargeObject));

//get it
var myObject = localStorage.getItem('myLargeObject');
console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(myObject));
```

Comment: I did not use local storage yet, but a service is starting to seem right. My initial route is an app loading screen, then I transfer to the actual start after app is loaded.